# Bash expect matching bash and ksh prompts

Tags: bash, expect

I have multiple systems with bash and ksh prompts:
bash prompts look like : [user1@wanserver bin]$ 
ksh prompts look like : $  on some and directory-name> on some systems

Using expect how can i match these ksh prompts. I am able to match the bash prompts, but not the ksh one's. I tried below for ksh, but it doesnt work. How can make this working?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set username [lindex $argv 0]
set password [lindex $argv 1]
set rt [lindex $argv 2]

spawn ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $username@$rt

expect {
timeout {
    puts "\n\nConnection timed out"
    exit 1
 }

 "*assword:" {
    send "$password\r"
  }
 }

 expect {
   "$ " {
    send "ls -l\r"
   }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why don't you use something safer that already implements exactly passing password via command line like `sshpass`? Why not just `sshpass -p $password -q .....@$rt ls -l` ?

Comment: Sshpass wont work with powerbroker

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there's a space after all the prompts, you can use a regular expression:

```
set prompt {[$>] $}
#...
expect -re $prompt
send "ls -l\r"
```

The first dollar sign is a literal dollar sign since it's  in a bracket expression. The second one is a regex "end of line" anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
 expect {
   "$ " {
   send "ls -l\r"
 }
```

use:

```
 expect {
   {$ } {
   send "ls -l\r"
 }
```

For details, see rules 4, 6 & 8 at http://tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm

Comment: {$ } doesn't work. Tried other combinations of $ with quotes , \ , it doesn't match the prompt.

Comment: Yes, Glenn's answer has a better match expression.